# How to convert HTML file into a hash in Perl?

Tags: perl, html-parsing, perl-module

Is there any simple way to convert a HTML file into a Perl hash? For example a working Perl modules or something?

I was search on cpan.org but did'nt find anything what can do what I want. I wanna do something like this:

```
use Example::Module;
my $hashref = Example::Module->new('/path/to/mydoc.html');
```

After this I want to refer to second div element something like this:

```
my $second_div = $hashref->{'body'}->{'div'}[1];
# or like this:
my $second_div = $hashref->{'body'}->{'div'}->findByClass('.myclassname');
# or like this:
my $second_div = $hashref->{'body'}->{'div'}->findById('#myid');
```

Is there any working solution for this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[HTML::TreeBuilder::XPath](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/HTML%3a%3aTreeBuilder%3a%3aXPath) gives you a lot more power than a simple hash would.

From the synopsis:

> ```
>   use HTML::TreeBuilder::XPath;
>   my $tree = HTML::TreeBuilder::XPath->new;
>   $tree->parse_file( "mypage.html");
> ```

```
  my $nb=$tree->findvalue('/html/body//p[@class="section_title"]/span[@class="nb"]');
  my $id=$tree->findvalue('/html/body//p[@class="section_title"]/@id');
  my $p= $html->findnodes('//p[@id="toto"]')->[0];

  my $link_texts= $p->findvalue( './a'); # the texts of all a elements in $p

  $tree->delete; # to avoid memory leaks, if you parse many HTML documents
```

More on [XPath](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/).

Answer (score 1):

`Mojo::DOM` ([docs found here](https://metacpan.org/module/Mojo%3a%3aDOM)) builds a simple DOM, that can be accessed in a CSS-selector style:

```
# Find
say $dom->at('#b')->text;
say $dom->find('p')->pluck('text');
say $dom->find('[id]')->pluck(attr => 'id');
```

In case you're using xhtml you could also use `XML::Simple`, which produces a data structure similar to the one you describe.